# How to get the data from local JSON, to the HTML page using ionic 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have this type of JSON file.

```
{
  "records": {
    "patients": {
      "day": "Today",
      "details": [
        {
          "name":"Diab",
          "stat":"Pending",
          "phno":"8197246465",
          "patNames":"Sandra Adams",
          "tests": [
            {"name":"MCHC","result":"positive"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How to bring each and every key into the html page or how to parse this one using service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do so by creating a service provider

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class yourService {
    constructor(public http:Http) {}

getData() {
    return this.http.get("YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_JSON_FILE")
        .map((res:Response) => res.json().YOUR_JSON_HEADER); //records in this case
  }
}
```

Define the service in your ts constructor and call the method to parse through  the data

```
this.yourService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log("what is in the data ", data);
  this.myjsondata = data;
});
```

Make sure to define the service provider in app.module.ts

For promises as in your case modify the code as follows:
In your service.

```
load() {
    console.log('json called');
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('assets/data/patient.json').map(response => {
            this.data = response.json();
            resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
}
```

Here you are getting data and resolving to promise. To use this in html you have to get the data in your component page as follows.

```
this.yourService.load().then((data) => {
      console.log("what is in the data ", data);
      this.patdata= data;
    });
```

You can now use the patdata in your html

```
<h1> {{patdata | json}} </h1>
```

Comment: `load(){
    console.log('json called');
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('assets/data/patient.json').subscribe(response => {
            this.data = response.json();
            console.log("json Data" );
            console.log(this.data);
            this.processData(this.data);
            console.log(this.data);
            resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
}`

Comment: code inside the comment converts your json to promise and then returns the data. While the code i have shared uses observable. You can use either of it based on your need. have a look on the difference between observable and promises before deciding :)

Comment: okay its working instead of `this.myjsondata = data` i use `this.patDat = data`. then how to bring it to html.

Comment: use the second part of my code in yout ts file to use it in html. Instead of keyword "subscribe" use "then" as you are returning promise