# GET http://localhost:4200/api/x.json 404 (Not Found) - angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

---

---

Hello, There is a problem with a project that does not recognize a json file - and I do not know why. Is there anything I need to change or make it work?

---

this is my folders:
[image]

---

this is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Ibrides } from "./brides";
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class brideService {
private _brideUrl = 'api/brides.json';
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { };

getBrides(): Observable<Ibrides[]> {

    return this._http.get<Ibrides[]>(this._brideUrl)
        .do(data => console.log('All:' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
}
}
```

---

this is my component

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Ibrides } from "./brides";
import { brideService } from "./brides.service"

@Component({
selector: 'pm-brides',
templateUrl: './brides_list.component.html',
styleUrls: []
})
export class bridesListComponent implements OnInit {


    constructor(private _brideService: brideService) {

    }
    errorMessage: string;
    brides: Ibrides[] = [];
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this._brideService.getBrides()
        .subscribe(brides => {
            this.brides = brides
        },

        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    }

}
```

Comment: It's clearly because there is no API available for that URL. As I see a json file, don't you need a mock API call by any chance?

Comment: I have an internal json file, and I'm just trying to call him.

Comment: set the `_brideUrl` to 'app/api/brides.json', i.e. `_brideUrl =  'app/api/brides.json'`.

Comment: Try to set path with your `src` directory, will work.

Comment: the same eror :(

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the file from the root level like this:

```
_brideUrl = 'app/api/brides.json'
```

For more information you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858663/how-to-get-the-data-from-local-json-to-the-html-page-using-ionic-2-typescript).